# android studio error "The following sdk component was not installed:tools"

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried installing android studio in ubuntu 12.04 using the following commands

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install android-studio

however the installation fails with the error "The following sdk  component was not installed:tools"

Note:

- I have also tried running using `sudo ./studio.sh`, but the problem remains
- Also Changing proxy settings didn't work

Any help regarding this is appreciated.Thanks